# How to find documents based on the result of a function mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have two schemas `user` and `driver` they both have latitude and longitude attributes.

At some point I want to query the database for nearby drivers, I will be sending the user's current location (latitude and longitude) and I have a function to calculate the distance between two points.

I am trying to do something like this:

find all drivers with distance less than 2 KM using my function ( the function is called calculateDistance).

**In code** this will be like this:

```
const drivers = await Driver.find();

const driversToReturn = drivers.filter(
    driver => calculateDistance(userLat, userLong, driver.latitude, driver.longitude) <= 2
);

res.status(200).json({
  drivers: driversToReturn
});
```

but I don't think this is the best way to do it, I've checked the mongoose virtuals but we can't pass params `(userLat and userLong)` to the `get` method of a virtual and I don't think instance methods are the solution.

so how should I do this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

**Driver Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const driverSchema = new Schema(
  {
    /** Required Attributes */
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    carBrand: { type: String, required: true },
    plateNumber: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    phoneNumber: { type: Number, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    latitude: { type: Number, required: true },
    longitude: { type: Number, required: true },

    /** Not Required Attributes */
    rating: { type: Number, required: false },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Driver = mongoose.model("Driver", driverSchema);

module.exports = Driver;
```

**User Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    /** Required Attributes */
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    phoneNumber: { type: Number, required: true },
    latitude: { type: Number, required: true },
    longitude: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**Users Controller**

```
const Driver = require("../models/driver");
const Order = require("../models/order");
const calculateDistance = require("../utils/calculateDistance");

const CIRCLE_RADIUS_IN_KM = 2;

exports.getNearbyDrivers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const userLat = req.body.userLat,
        userLong = req.body.userLong,
        drivers = await Driver.find();

    const driversToReturn = drivers.filter(
        (driver) =>
            calculateDistance(
                userLat,
                userLong,
                driver.latitude,
                driver.longitude
            ) <= CIRCLE_RADIUS_IN_KM
    );

    res.status(200).json({
      drivers: driversToReturn,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }

    next(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you checked out [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/)?

Comment: @ray no I haven't actually, I will check it now and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @ray I have seen the $function and It returns an empty array always, could you provide sample implementation of it. Note: I am using mongoose not MongoClient

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot provide such example without having your sample dataset,  the function and the corresponding expected output.

Comment: why don't you make a mongoose query directly instead of retreiving all driver and doint a filter in js ?

Comment: @ray ok no problem my friend

Comment: @Wax that is exactly what I am looking for, I know this approach (that I'm using) is wrong

Comment: @ray I'll edit the post and provide the code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code from the documentation of Mongoose that can help you with that I think :

```js
    const denver = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-104.9903, 39.7392] };
    return City.create({ name: 'Denver', location: denver }).
      then(() => City.findOne().where('location').within(colorado)).
      then(doc => assert.equal(doc.name, 'Denver'));
```

and here is the link : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html

Comment: I'll check your answer and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: I understand now, you suggest that I make a geoarea where the center is the user's location and then query for drivers within this geoarea, right?

Comment: yep, that is what I had in mind. As Mongo works pretty well with geoJson I think it might be a good idea to use that.